# Auto implement dependency injection when inherit from interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Recently, I work with ASP Boilerteample. It has classes to implement dependency injection such as `ITransientDependency`.

When a class implements the `ITransientDependency` interface, it can be injected into the constructor without any configuration in the startup file.

I want to do the same but don't know how. Please tell me what to do, is there a library to support or a document.

Comment: A class doesn't **inherit** from an interface - it **implements** it......

Comment: Do you want repeat the same behavior in some other DI library?

Comment: Look at this will help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490264/mechanism-for-dependency-injection-to-provide-the-most-specific-implementation-o

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via reflection, however it is not trivial.

The following assumes you have a Dependency Injection container set up.

### Step 1

First you need to get all the types from all current assemblies, but only those that are not abstracts or interfaces (i.e. those that can be created):

```cs
var types = from t in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            where t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ITransientDependency))
            && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface
            select t;
```

This will return a list of `Type` objects representing classes that implement `ITransientDependency` from all currently loaded assemblies.

### Step 2

Next, you need to add those to the Dependency Injection container.  Assuming you are using Microsoft's `IServiceCollection` you then do this (e.g. in the `ConfigureServices` method in your Startup class):

```cs
foreach (var t in types)
{
    services.AddTransient(t);
}
```

Note: this is not really DI best practice.  Normally you should inject interfaces, not implementations, and add each one like this:

```cs
services.AddTransient<ISomeDependency, SomeImpl>();
services.AddTransient<IAnotherDependency, AnotherImpl>();
// and so on
```

This helps with test-driven development, as you can create a mock implementation of an interface, but not of an implementation.

### Step 3

Finally, you can now inject these into a class via the constructor:

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(SomeDependency dep)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You need to be careful doing this as you could introduce issues at runtime - for example, the dependencies of all your `ITransientDependency` implementations *also* need to be added to your DI container, and they can't have any other dependencies (e.g. value types).

### Warning

The `GetTypes()` method used in the first step can throw an exception so you would need to handle that.  I have done this in the past through pushing this into an extension method:

```cs
internal static IEnumerable<Type> GetLoadableTypes(this Assembly assembly)
{
    try
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes();
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        return e.Types.Where(t => t != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, but it's not what I want.
[This is docs of aspboilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection)

Comment: OK, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking then - those docs explain how to register dependencies [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#registering-dependencies) - I assumed you were asking how to implement something like what they do?